# Laravel - Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: laravel

Something has changed since last Laravel update....i can't create new project with this command:

```
sudo composer create-project laravel/laravel template --prefer-dist
```

i get this error:
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

[image]
What do i need to change to be able to make new laravel project?

Comment: I'm getting the same error on fresh laravel install. I tried installing 5.1.* and 5.2.* version with composer and got the same error.

Comment: I can't recreate the problem, are you installing in an empty folder?

Comment: yes...what command do you use @SebHallin??

Comment: I used the same as you, but in Windows 10 instead.. I don't think it should be any problem for the installation, but you use PHP >= 5.5.9? Also, have you tried composer self-update?

Comment: laravel@laravel:/var/www/html$ sudo composer self-update
[sudo] password for laravel: 
You are already using composer version 1.1.3 (stable channel).

Comment: [same problem?](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/problems-installing-laravel?page=1)

Comment: now it's working...i just can't believe it....it is possible that i have hit the exact moment when they have changing the files? could this be it...this can't be true. they are still updating it seems to me! I keep getting different errors but everytime something further

Comment: they have finished updating repository...now everything works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens if the packages don't exist and the reason why they don't exist is probably because exactly at that moment the packages are being updated from developers side!

So you just need to wait a little (minutes) and try again later.

Comment: Sometimes that's the case, but not always.

Comment: What else can happen?